# How to rewrite a subdomain in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im trying to simplify the subdomain complexity perception to the user so I would like to mask the subdomain.

My goal is the following:

When the user tries to get here

```
blog.example.com/blog/whatever
```

I would like to mask the subdomain to be

```
example.com/blog/whatever
```

Same content served but with the subdomain hidden.

I have tried the following but with no success.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://blog\.example.com\/blog [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Update: Rewrite module is enabled

Comment: Are you seeing any errors on these rules? Or do you have other rules in your htaccess apart from these rules? Kindly do let us know on these questions.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://blog\.example.com\/blog [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

The HTTP `Host` header (ie. the value of the `HTTP_HOST` server variable) contains the hostname only, ie. `blog.example.com`. It does not contain the full absolute URL.

So, your rule should be like this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog($|/) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This matches the URL-path `/blog` or `/blog/<whatever>` (but not `/blog<something>`) and redirects to the same URL-path at `example.com` (+ HTTPS). The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the root-relative URL-path, starting with a slash.

You were redirecting to HTTP, but I assume this must be HTTPS?

You should clear your browser cache before testing and test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: Yes, you are right, should be https

Comment: @Imnl How did you get on with this?